# Correlation for a view oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How do you calculate the correlation for a view in Oracle SQL.

I have no problem using the `CORR_S` function for a table but get errors when using on a view.

This is the view created.

```
CREATE VIEW staffavg
AS
SELECT C.staffid AS "staffid", (SELECT S.age
                 FROM staff S
                 WHERE S.staffid = C.staffid) AS "age", ROUND(AVG(C.courseevaluation),2 ) AS "courseavg"
FROM course C
GROUP BY C.staffid
ORDER BY C.staffid
```

This is the function I use to get the correlation

```
SELECT 
CORR_S(courseavg, age) AS "coefficient",
CORR_S(courseavg, age, 'TWO_SIDED_SIG') AS "two sided sig"
FROM staffavg
```

This is the error

> ORA-00904: "AGE": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:    
>   *Action:
>  Error at Line: 23 Column: 19

Comment: Oracle isn't SQL Server, they 're different products. Please don't use unrelated tags in your question.

Comment: oh sorry my bad

Comment: `"age"`, as created? (I.e. lower case, double-quoted.)

Comment: I dont understand..

Comment: `CORR_S(courseavg, "age")`

Comment: The moral is: don't double-quote identifiers when creating objects, as it makes them case-sensitive.

Comment: oh alright, didn't know that, thank you :)